# Cisco SSL VPN with Windows 7 Client?

Tags: vpn, cisco, router

I have a Cisco ISR model 1841 running IOS 12.4

I would like to replace my aged SonicWall pro2040 with it.

The main problem I am trying to find a solution to is whether or not I am first create an SSL VPN server on the 1841. From what I found that is pretty much a yes if you have the right IOS. Which I am not sure if I have the right one or not.

Second I am trying to figure out if it possible to set up the 1841 and connect to it using the Windows 7 built in VPN client.

I am aware of the Cisco AnyConnect software but I cannot afford licensing and the router is not covered under a SmartNet support contract or anything.

Pretty much is this possible? Or should I look for another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do allow me to present you with the following:

**Option 1:**
I am afraid, within the scope of my knowledge, that you will need to look at setting up a 
L2TP configuration which will work directly with the Windows-based VPN connectivity options.

This option will be require a fair bit of elbow grease and documentation (so that you can reverse your way out of sticky situations). Of course, if you have the prior knowledge and experience, this should be rather straightforward.

**Option 2:**
If you would like to use the Cisco AnyConnect application, then licensing will be the only hurdle that you will need to clear.

This option is the easiest to implement and the most costly to deal with.

---

I do hope that you will find the above information useful. Good luck.

Comment: Well I guess there is always to possibility of just running a VPN server behind the router but that has its own problems that are out of the scope this question.